# Duplicate symbols in Microsoft C library

Tags: c, windows, visual-c++, linker, portable-executable

I'm writing a linker for Windows PE format object files, and I've got to the stage where it can link together object files produced by the Microsoft compiler, but when I try to link with libcmt.lib I get a lot of duplicate symbols.

For example, `cosl` is defined by three different objects in the library. All three refer to definitions in different places, and all three look genuine, e.g. they point to text segments named `.text$mn` and have storage class `IMAGE_SYM_CLASS_EXTERNAL`.

Is it the case that these are alternate versions and the linker is supposed to pick one based on some criterion, or am I misunderstanding something about the semantics of the PE library format?

Comment: I assume you verified that you don't get a "duplicate symobl" error when compiling/linking with the regular compiler tools, to make sure it's a problem of your linker code?

Comment: @Devolus Yes, the Microsoft linker is working fine.

Comment: Does the offset also point to different objects?

Comment: A rough guess is that you not handling COMDAT sections properly, used by inline functions like cosl().  Read section 5.5.6 of the [pecoff specification](http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/b/a/eba1050f-a31d-436b-9281-92cdfeae4b45/pecoff.doc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As referenced in the comments, the OP is not processing the COMDAT section properly.
https://download.microsoft.com/download/9/C/5/9C5B2167-8017-4BAE-9FDE-D599BAC8184A/pecoff.docx

Comment: HTTP Error 404.